# Customize home page in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know is a very dummy question, but i can't find any where how to make the changes that I want

I have this Demo : `http://ch-consulting.ro/animation-fountain/`  that I want to add to my page http://ch-consulting.ro/.
I tried to see every menu in my Dashbord in wordpress, but I didn't found any menu from where to choose that demo.

Please help me , from where  can I choose that demo.

Comment: Have you checked Appearance->Customize ?

Comment: Yes, i'ved done that, but I can't find in that menus, somthing to add that demo.

Comment: the theme you use doesn't have documentation? maybe there are demo content to import for every demo

Comment: Yes, i have, but even there i can't found, is very frustrating :(